# Weird reformatting, cannot tell what is responsible

Tags: hooks, formatting

In my code I have bindings for two reformatters that are supposed to be applied upon saving relevant code:

```
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'ocp-indent-buffer
    (merlin-mode))))

(add-hook 'reason-mode-hook (lambda ()
                (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'refmt-before-save)
                (merlin-mode)))
```

Yet for some reason my code is getting formatted weirdly at times (and not just the OCaml/ReasonML, my Emacs Lisp code can get formatted really weirdly. I'm not sure what triggers the weird formatting; usually it's after I delete something or paste something in.

Here is an example of normal formatting:
[image]

And here is an example of the weird formatting:
[image]

I wish I had the braincells to save the message log so I could post it here but I forgot to. It happens every few hours; if it happens again I will post my messages buffer here.

Answer (score 1):

Please always indent your Emacs Lisp code correctly, you can use
`C-M-q` (`indent-pp-sexp`) to do that, then you should be able to
notice you have:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'ocp-indent-buffer
          (merlin-mode))
```

but I guess what you want is this instead:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'ocp-indent-buffer)
(merlin-mode)
```

---

As for you question, it is because you are changing
`before-save-hook`'s global value, thus whenever you save a buffer,
`ocp-indent-buffer` will be executed, it doesn't matter which Major
mode you are currently in. It appears that you want to run
`ocp-indent-buffer` on saving only OCaml buffers, you should change
`before-save-hook`'s buffer-local value in OCaml buffers by setting
`add-hook`'s fourth argument `LOCAL` to non-nil:

```el
(add-hook
 'tuareg-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'ocp-indent-buffer nil t)
   (merlin-mode)))
```

Comment: Thank you xuchunyang! I knew I did something stupid. I wish I could upvote your post. That is exactly what I was looking for.